# How to embed multi-line block of text in maths

Tags: math-mode

What is the best way to embed a multi-line block of text, surrounded by curly braces, in maths mode? The best I can do is the following hack.

```
\[
{\text{bounded WD-representations} 
\brace 
\text{of $W_K$ over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_l$}}
\]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you think it's hackish, but my guess is because you want it to represent a set, and thus be arbitrarily many lines high?  In that case, I would set the text in a `\parbox`:

```
\newcommand{\pctext}[2]{\text{\parbox{#1}{\centering #2}}}
\[ \left\{ \pctext{1.8in}{bounded WD-representations of $W_K$ over
                          $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_l$} \right\} \]
```

This either allows TeX to break things or to explicitly break text with `\\`.  The downside is that you have to specify the exact width.  I tried using the [pbox package](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pbox/), which allows you to write `\pbox{\textwidth}{...}` to get text fitted to the longest line in the `...`; unfortunately, I couldn't get `\centering` to work (except for on the last line), which makes things look really ugly.

Also, in general, the TeX commands which read their previous argument, such as `\atop`, `\atopwithdelims`, and thus by extention `\brace`, aren't recommended.  The amsmath package provides the `\genfrac` command to do this; in your case, you'd have

```
\genfrac{\{}{\}}
        {0pt}{}
        {\text{bounded WD-representations}}
        {\text{of $W_K$ over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}_l$}}
```

I'm not 100% percent sure why this is, though.  But wiser heads than mine have said so, so I tend to pay attention :-)